# How to get multiple rows key values from counter column family in Cassandra .

Tags: java, cassandra, hector, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli

I am new bie in cassandra and i want to fetch multiple row keys in column counter family,just like MultigetSliceQuery.is it possible or not ???
for example my colunfamily definition is

```
create column family MyCounters 
with default_validation_class=CounterColumnType 
and comparator=UTF8Type;
```

and data structure is

```
RowKey:111111
=>name=like, value=2222
=>name=share, value=2542
=>name=comment, value=3532

RowKey:111112
=>name=like, value=2542
=>name=share, value=25524
=>name=comment, value=32

RowKey:111113
=>name=like, value=22
=>name=share, value=22
=>name=comment, value=32

RowKey:111114
=>name=like, value=22
=>name=share, value=542
=>name=comment, value=332

RowKey:111115
=>name=like, value=949
=>name=share, value=226
=>name=comment, value=342
```

now i want to fetch all row keys using multi getslice query.it is possible to fetch record using multiget slice query or any other query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i got the solution

```
MultigetSliceCounterQuery<String, String> query=HFactory.createMultigetSliceCounterQuery(keyspace, se, se);
query.setColumnFamily("MyCounters").setKeys(list).setRange(null, null, false, 3);
CounterRows<String,String> resultRows1 = query.execute().get();

for (CounterRow<String, String> row : resultRows1) {
    System.out.println("Row Key "+ row.getKey());
    for (HCounterColumn<String> col : row.getColumnSlice().getColumns())
        System.out.println("column Name "+col.getName()+"column value "+col.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use Kundera. Run simple JPQL to get multiple results.